# Deck.js changing displayed slide size based on slide content

Tags: css, deck.js

When the content of my slides in a deck.js presentation gets larger than the vertical window, the browsers are shrinking the displayed content.

The more content, the smaller the display gets.  The effect seems 'page' wide, as the top left corner of the slide moves further away from the top left corner of the browser window -- as if I were zooming out from the page.  I can navigate to the all of content with the mouse, but no scrollbar appears.

What is going on here, and how do I get control of the display size in these situations?

(Apologies for a possibly poor question -- I don't know quite enough CSS to know what additional information I should or could provide here.  I'd be glad to add in answer to questions.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep consistent (constant) font size and layout across slides, I would recommend using the "fit" extension from this page http://home.heeere.com/tech-deckjs-ext.html .

On the negative side, this extension currently prevents you from using the horizontal and vertical transition themes. It could be patched to allow these transitions.

On the positive side, this extension will allow you to have a scrollbar on your slide. You can do that by adding the following style in your page:

```
        div.deck-container > .slide {overflow-y: scroll;}
```

Comment: Thanks!  And sorry for the delay looking at this.  Very helpful.